# Maven BOM: Super BOM which gathers all BOMs?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

We are currently thinking about managing the versions of our own artifacts with Maven BOMs. Our current idea is that each developer group keeps a BOM with the recent versions of their artifacts and that for each release, a "super BOM" is constructed of all these BOMs. So I would like to know:

Is it reasonable (and technically possible) to have a BOM that includes other BOMs with "import" statements? Are there drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: You mean POM, right?

Comment: I mean BOM. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Sorry for the semi-rude comment, which was based on ignorance; this is a new concept for me :)

Comment: Came across your question looking for the exact same thing. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar We discouraged super BOMs, but some developers/groups crafted their own. It is ok, but has the downside that super BOMs need updates very often, and that you become inflexible if you want to replace just a single BOM by a different version.

Comment: @JFMeier So it's technically possible to have super BOMs? Can you share one (redacting whatever you need to), so that I see what's the syntax to import a BOM in it? Other than your question, I didn't find any other reference to a super BOM.

Comment: You just define a BOM where you declare all the other BOMs in dependencyManagement with "<scope>import</scope>
<type>pom</type>"